how to access each json object in a array using for loop?
{
  "item1" : [{"index":"1"},{"id":"1","name":"npm","result":"expected text1"},{"id":"2","name":"yarn","result":"expected text2"},{"id":"3","name":"pnpm","result":"expected text3"}],
  "item2":  [{"index":"2"},{"id":"1","name":"npm","result":"expected text1 for item2"},{"id":"2","name":"yarn","result":"expected text2 for item 2"},{"id":"3","name":"pnpm","result":"expected text3 for item 2"}]

}

I want to access item1 and item2 using for loop?
how can I do it?

This question is similar to: Loop (for each) over an array in JavaScript. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It would be helpful if you tried to explain what you tried so far and why it didn't work. This is the kind of post that demonstrates a lack of effort on the part of the author. You could say "So I've been learning about this new thing called for loops which I know how it works but I can't fathom how to use it with object fields..." and then we could give you a hint telling you how to access the object field first so you can proceed with your task (It would be wonderful if you told us what problems you had doing that instead of waiting for us to tell you to do it).

for ( let i=1; i<3; i++){
test(show item${i}, async ({page})=>{
console.log(myData.item${i})
})
}



const data = {
  "item1": [
    { "index": "1" },
    { "id": "1", "name": "npm", "result": "expected text1" },
    { "id": "2", "name": "yarn", "result": "expected text2" },
    { "id": "3", "name": "pnpm", "result": "expected text3" }
  ],
  "item2": [
    { "index": "2" },
    { "id": "1", "name": "npm", "result": "expected text1 for item2" },
    { "id": "2", "name": "yarn", "result": "expected text2 for item 2" },
    { "id": "3", "name": "pnpm", "result": "expected text3 for item 2" }
  ]
};

for (const key in data) {
  for (const obj of data[key]) {
    console.log(obj);
  }
}



